# Look-up table with different values for each column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got one table that is a set of all of my columns, their possible corresponding values, and the description for each one of those values. For example, the table looks like this:

```
ID Column Value Description
1  Age    A     Age_20-30
2  Age    B     Age_30-50
3  Age    C     Age_50-75
4  Geo    A     Big_City
5  Geo    B     Suburbs
6  Geo    C     Rural_Town
```

And so on.. Next, I have my main data frame that is populated with the column values. What I'd like to do is switch all values in each column with their corresponding description.

Old:

```
ID Age Geo
1  A   B
2  A   A
3  C   A
4  B   C
5  C   C
```

New:

```
ID Age       Geo
1  Age_20-30 Suburbs
2  Age_20-30 Big_City
3  Age_50-75 Big_City
4  Age_30-50 Rural_Town
5  Age_50-75 Rural_Town
```

Now I know how I can do this for one column using the following (where lookup_df is a table for only one of my columns):

```
old <- lookup_df$Value
new <- lookup_df$Description
df$Age <- new[match(df$Age, old, nomatch = 0)]
```

But I am struggling to do this for all columns. My full set of data has >100 columns so doing this manually for each column isn't really an option (at least in terms of efficiency). Any help or pointers in the right direction would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the first dataset into to a list of named vectors.  Use that to match and replace the second dataset

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(df1[c('Value', 'Description')], df1$Column), 
          function(x) setNames(x$Description, x$Value))
df2[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) y[x], df2[-1], lst1)
```

-output

```
df2
# ID       Age        Geo
#1  1 Age_20-30    Suburbs
#2  2 Age_20-30   Big_City
#3  3 Age_50-75   Big_City
#4  4 Age_30-50 Rural_Town
#5  5 Age_50-75 Rural_Town
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Column = c("Age", "Age", "Age", "Geo", 
"Geo", "Geo"), Value = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
Description = c("Age_20-30", 
"Age_30-50", "Age_50-75", "Big_City", "Suburbs", "Rural_Town"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Age = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C"), Geo = c("B", 
"A", "A", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this on data with lot of columns you can get the data in long format, join it with the first dataframe and (if needed) get it back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% select(-ID), 
             by = c('name' = 'Column', 'value' = 'Value')) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Description)

#     ID Age       Geo       
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>     
#1     1 Age_20-30 Suburbs   
#2     2 Age_20-30 Big_City  
#3     3 Age_50-75 Big_City  
#4     4 Age_30-50 Rural_Town
#5     5 Age_50-75 Rural_Town
```